# No access panel in the Tab Document Interface ..?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have making the Tab Document Interface like that Firefox. I want to make a some portion of the page refresh Time to Time. I think have you seen already Cricket Page Refresh page after some time. I have used panel for the refresh for page but panel not show. I have try but can't do this.I am working at windows form. plz any body solve this problem and thanks in advance. My coding part here:-

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewTab();
        toolStripTextBox1.Text = "Go to website";
        toolStripTextBox2.Text = "Google Search text here";
        toolStripComboBox1.Text = "Google.co.in";
        toolStripComboBox1.Items.Add("Google.co.in");
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
        panel1.Show();
        label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
    TabPage tp;
    WebBrowser wb;
    private void AddNewTab()
    {
        tp=new TabPage();
        wb=new WebBrowser();
        wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);
        wb.Focus();
        wb.Url = new Uri("http://google.co.in");
        wb.Dock=DockStyle.Fill;
        tp.Controls.Add(wb);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1, tp);
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = tp;

    }
```

[image]

Comment: no there any body can solve my problem????????????????????????????????